# How to always show scrollbar for ListView in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

The gist of my problem is that I have a ListView, and if there are more ListCells in it than how many its size can accomodate, the scrollbar appears and "pushes" the content to the left. How do I set the scrollbar to always be present regardless of the number of ListCells?

Below is my implementation:

```
<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <ListView fx:id="ingredientListView" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS"/>
</VBox>
```

There doesn't seem to be the `fadeScrollbars="false"` property that is available in ListView in Android. Appreciate any help!

Comment: Unfortunately the virtual controls (e.g. `ListView`, `TableView`, etc.) don't give any control over the scroll bars, nor do the default skins of these virtual controls. While there are ways to make it look as if the scroll bars never appear, I'm not sure how to do it the other way around.

Comment: Hmm that is unfortunate. I've seen solutions for ScrollPanes and might give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: The problem is `ListView` does not use a `ScrollPane` internally but rather manages its own `ScrollBar`s directly. And the implementation doesn't re-implement the `ScrollBarPolicy` functionality of `ScrollPane`.

Comment: @kleopatra Do you have an idea on how to do that? I've tried forcing the `visible` property of the vertical scroll bar to be always true but that didn't work.

Comment: @Slaw hmm .. now that you mentioned it .. me too ;) Sry, remembered incorrectly ..